# Then is undefined msg shown using md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My Controller:

```
myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($timeout, $q) {
var self = this;

self.uom = loaduom();
self.selecteditem = null;
self.searchtext = null;
self.querysearch = searchuom;

function searchuom(query) {
    var result = query ? uom.filter(createfilter(query)) : uom;
    var deferred = $q.defer;
    $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve(result); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
}

function loaduom() {
    var itms = ' Pcs ,Pak ,Bag ,Box ,Ltr ,Mltr ,c.m. ,m.m ,mtr ,kg ,gms ,sqft ';
    return itms.split(/,+/g).map(function (uom) {
        return {
            value: uom.toLowerCase,
            display: uom
        };
    })
}
function createfilter(query) {
    var lowercase = angular.lowercase(query);

    return function filterfn(uom) {
        return uom.value.selecetdindexof(lowercase) === 0;
    }
}
```

});

View :

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
<form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()"name="srchform">
    <md-autocomplete 
        required
        md-input-name="autocompleteField"
        md-input-minlength="2"
        md-input-maxlength="18"
        md-no-cache="myctrl.noCache"
        md-selected-item="myctrl.selecteditem"
        md-search-text="myctrl.searchtext"
        md-items="item in myctrl.searchuom(myctrl.searchtext)"
        md-item-text="item.display"
        md-require-match=""
        md-floating-label="sample DD list">
        <md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="">{{item.display}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
</form>
```

Hi, i am beginner in angular material design. Now i just try an example from tutorial for **md-autocomplete** directive.

I seeing error on my console like this,

```
 angular.min.js:124 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at me (angular-material.min.js:14)
at ve (angular-material.min.js:14)
at angular-material.min.js:13
at angular.min.js:137
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:148)
at b.$apply (angular.min.js:151)
at Object.$$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.min.js:300)
at Object.$setViewValue (angular.min.js:299)
at HTMLInputElement.l (angular.min.js:183)
at jg (angular.min.js:40) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
```

I don't know what i am make mistake in this code. please guide me.

Thanks in advance, :-)

Answer (score 0):

md-items="item in myctrl.searchuom(myctrl.searchtext)". md-items is supposed to be looping through your content much like the ng-repeat.
I see you currently have the value of searchtext = null. 
This would give you the error you see.

To resolve, in place of: myctrl.searchuom(myctrl.searchtext), place the array you hope to loop through.